# Is there a website that will allow me to create a fictional calendar?

Tags: worldbuilding-resources, time-keeping, software-recommendations

Is there a website that will allow me to create a fictional calendar? I have already created the actual system, named the months, days of the week, and so on, but I would like to create an actual calendar so I can visualize it better. I would want to be able to include things like holidays, festivals, and celebrations along with character birthdates and other important story related events. I know there are plenty of websites that allow you to make your own calendar with our calendar system, but are there any that let you create a new system?

Comment: Excel, I suppose? What functionality do you want exactly?

Comment: If you're using a similar 'grid' system, Microsoft Word, Excel and Publisher all have fully customizable forms in their products, names and date are up to you. <Hint> most cultures in our past use events and periods that are largely astronomical in nature.

Comment: I would say Google Sheets, 'cause free, but yes, a spreadsheet should suffice nicely.

Comment: Two minutes' Googling returns the moderately robust [Fantasy Calendar](https://fantasy-calendar.com/) site, which seems to include everything you've asked for.

Comment: There are many coders here, if you describe the calendar rules we may be able to make a script that renders your calendar.

Answer (score 6):

Is [this](https://donjon.bin.sh/fantasy/calendar/) what you are looking for?  Pretty basic, but it'll let you fiddle with stuff and make sure you did your math right.

Another possibility is [Fantasy Calendar](https://fantasy-calendar.com/calendar?action=generate) which allows you to play with a number of variables.

Comment: If you would, please take a moment to appropriately add that link to our [Worldbuilding Resources page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/143606/40609).

Comment: @JBH - and done